# How can I convert specific fromat in laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, date, eloquent

```
[ { "from": "2021/05/10", "to": "2021/05/14" }, { "from": "2021/05/17", "to": "2021/05/20" }]
```

into

```
1 "2021/05/10"
2 "2021/05/14"
3 "2021/05/17"
4 "2021/05/20"
```

so it looks like this in a database. ofc there can be more than two

```
$holiday = new Utility;

$h = $request->get('holiday'); -> [ { "from": "2021/05/10"..
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's a collection, you could just use the `collapse()` method.

```
$h = $request->get('holiday'); 
/*
Illuminate\Support\Collection {
   all: [
       Utility {
           +"from": "2021/05/10",
           +"to": "2021/05/14",
       },
       Utility {
           +"from": "2021/05/17",
           +"to": "2021/05/20",
       },
   ],
}
*/
```

```php
$h->map(function ($utility) { return [$utility->from, $utility->to]; });
/*
Illuminate\Support\Collection {
   all: [
       [
           "2021/05/10",
           "2021/05/14",
       ],
       [
           "2021/05/17",
           "2021/05/20",
       ],
   ],
}
*/
```

```php
$h->map(function ($utility) { return [$utility->from, $utility->to]; })
  ->collapse();
/* 
Illuminate\Support\Collection {
   all: [
       "2021/05/10",
       "2021/05/14",
       "2021/05/17",
       "2021/05/20",
   ],
}
*/
```

```php
$h->map(function ($utility) { return [$utility->from, $utility->to]; })
  ->collapse()
  ->all();
/* 
[
    "2021/05/10",
    "2021/05/14",
    "2021/05/17",
    "2021/05/20",
],
*/
```

---

If `$h = $request->get('holiday');` is not a Collection but a json string like the one below,

```
[{"from":"2021/05/10","to":"2021/05/14"},{"from":"2021/05/17","to":"2021/05/20"}]
```

You can convert it to a Collection with `collect(json_decode($h))` and do the same

`->map(...)->collapse()->all()` sequence.

---

And if you want to echo those values in a blade file (with the numbering), you could do it like this:

```
@foreach ($h as $index => $value)
    {{ $index + 1 }} {{ $value }}<br>
@endforeach
```

Comment: How do I save it into the database though?

Comment: Depends on what tables/models you have.

Comment: It throws an error Call to a member function map() on array

Comment: $h = $request->get('holiday'); is an array

Comment: Trying to get property 'from' of non-object still not wokrin

Comment: use `['from']` and `['to']` instead of `->from` and `->to`

Comment: Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given, called in D:\Projects\lumen food\vendor\illuminate\database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php on line 681